# Mapping of Disks and underneath "Primary/Logical" Partition(s) by Unix Terminal Prompt Commands and GRUB Prompt Commands (With GRUB Naming Convention)

Tags: partitioning, grub2, mount, lubuntu, fdisk

In Unix ***("Ubuntu/lUbuntu")*** is there any ***command*** or ***any easy way to find mapping*** for ***Disk + Logical and/or Primary Partition Information*** between the  ***"ls"*** output **at** ***"GNU GRUB Bootloader Prompt (GRUB Prompt) while booting"***  and ***"fdisk -l* , *mount*
*(if required , also alongwith superuser privileges)"*** output at ***"lUbuntu/Ubuntu terminal prompt"*** **?**

Example : Mapping between **(hd*****[x]*****,msdos*****[y]*****) - by GRUB ls** and **/dev/sda*****[z]*** **by unix terminal commands mount , fdisk and others** etc where **"x" denotes base disk number , "y" denotes partition/sub-partitions number , "z" denotes partition/sub-partitions number** .

**P.S.** ***I have used lUbuntu 18.04 Alternative ISO (x64) for installing lUbuntu OS and used "Guided Partitioning" by "Partition Manager" while installing lUbuntu !***

Comment: The `a` in `sda` refers to the first sata disk. Which is `hd0`. Now, `y=0` corresponds to `z=1`. The main thing to remember is, in grub the counting starts from 0. In rest of Ubuntu counting starts from 1.

Comment: Also see [the answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/182161/grub-how-find-partition-number-hd0-x) for more. Note in `/dev/hda` the `hd` refers to PATA disks, which we don't see anymore. The SATA disks starts with `sd`.

Comment: So , 

***"y"*** starts from ***"0"*** 

and 

***"z=y+1"*** . 

By this way , ***"z"*** starts from ***1*** .

***"a"*** in **"sd*a**"* corresponds to **hd**___(0)___

***"b"*** in **"sd*b*"** corresponds to **hd**___(1)___

and so on respectively !

Correct me if i am wrong somewhere @user68186

Comment: You got it. I am not sure if this mapping breaks under some circumstances.